# Odata Union results JavaScript

Tags: java, rest, kendo-ui, odata

I would like to merge the results of two odata queries, querying different entities form a 3rd party in JS and Bind to a kendo-ui grid. I kinda want a union statement.

Can anymore give me a steer if this is possible?

Comment: I suggest adding an example of what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays in javascript, you can call array1.concat(array2) and use that result to bind to a grid.

Sample http://jsbin.com/hahamo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Robin they are not arrays but Json calls.